# Writing resilient recursive code that will return results from a big json file

Tags: python, json, dictionary, recursion

I have written a recursive code. I want more experienced people to tell me how resillient and fail-safe is my code:

I have a json file (Json file can be as big as 300MB):

```
[
  {
    "modules": {
      "webpages": []
    },
    "webpages": {
      "ip_addr": {
        "value": "127.0.0.1",
        "tags": []
      },
      "http": {
        "status": {
          "value": "Unavailable",
          "tags": []
        },
        "title": {
          "value": "403 Forbidden",
          "tags": [
            {
              "category": "Server Code",
              "match": "403"
            },
            {
              "category": "Interesting Words",
              "match": "Forbidden"
            }
          ]
        },
        "server": {
          "value": "Apache",
          "tags": [
            {
              "category": "Apache Server",
              "match": "Apache"
            }
          ]
        }
      },

      "redirects": [],
      "robottxt": null
    }
  },
  {
    "modules": {
      "webpages": []
    }
  }
]
```

I want to return value keys where tags are populated.
So I want to ignore:
"status": {
"value": "Unavailable",
"tags": []
},

But I want to return the **title** and **server** values. I also want to return ip_addr.value

I have written this code:

```
def getAllValues(nestedDictionary, firstArray, firstObj, firstUseful):

    returnedArray = firstArray
    tempValue = firstObj
    useful = firstUseful

    for key, value in nestedDictionary.items():

        ipString = nestedDictionary.get("ip_addr")

        if ipString is not None:
            ipValue = ipString.get("value")
            useful = {"ip_add": ipValue}

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            temp = {
                "Key": key,
                "useful": useful,
            }
            getAllValues(value, returnedArray, temp, useful)
        else:
            if key == "value":
                tempValue["value"] = value

            if key == "tags" and isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:
                tempValue["tags"] = value

                returnedArray.append(tempValue)
    return returnedArray
```

The above code should return:

```
[
  {
    "Key": "title",
    "value": "403 Forbidden",
    "useful": { "ip_addr": "127.0.0.1" },
    "tags": [
      {
        "category": "Server Code",
        "match": "403"
      },
      {
        "category": "Interesting Words",
        "match": "Forbidden"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Key": "server",
    "value": "Apache",
    "useful": { "ip_addr": "127.0.0.1" },
    "tags": [
      {
        "category": "Apache Server",
        "match": "Apache"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Its a long post, but hopefully, someone can give me some assurance :)

Comment: Your code has a typo.  If you're trying to figure out if your code is "resilient" you should start by running it at least once with some test data.

Comment: Does your solution work? If it does your post **may** be better suited for CodeReview. Please take the [CodeReview Tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting there. Don't forget to review their [on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page.

Comment: I have run it with test data and works fine. I slightly changed the code to post it here. There may be a typo for that reason.

Where is the typo?

Comment: Thanks for bringing my attention to CodeReview. I was not aware of it. 
Total beginner here :)